# Mongodb slow call in com.mongodb.Reponse.java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a 3 node replicaset , while doing performance testing I see many calls to mongo are slow.

There are no slow queries in the logs , the mms console doesnt point me to anything (no page faults , index misses , cpu , memory). From profiling the app I see all the calls are slow in the below line

```
                 CommonRepositoryImpl.aggregate:242 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                    MongoTemplate.execute:402 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                     CommonRepositoryImpl$3.doInCollection:243 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                      CommonRepositoryImpl$3.doInCollection:248 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                       DBCollection.aggregate:1307 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                        DB.command:244 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                         DB.command:262 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                          DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find:288 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                           DBTCPConnector.call:216 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                            DBTCPConnector.innerCall:244 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                             DBPort.call:92 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                              DBPort.go:142 (0ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
                               Response.<init>:40 (5856ms self time, 5856 ms total time)
```

I checked which line in Response.java was slow (readFully)

```
   final byte [] b = new byte[36];
   Bits.readFully(in, b); 
   int pos = 0;
```

I am not sure how to interpret this and what is cause of the slowness, any clue on what might be causing the slowness would be a great help

```
rs_default:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "xrr",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 784576,
        "avgObjSize" : 2757.876167509585,
        "dataSize" : 2163763452,
        "storageSize" : 2698293248,
        "numExtents" : 49,
        "indexes" : 64,
        "indexSize" : 791019824,
        "fileSize" : 6373244928,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}

db.VehicleReview.stats()
    {
            "ns" : "xrr.VehicleReview",
            "count" : 399933,
            "size" : 1264702320,
            "avgObjSize" : 3162.285482818372,
            "storageSize" : 1476620288,
            "numExtents" : 19,
            "nindexes" : 39,
            "lastExtentSize" : 386654208,
            "paddingFactor" : 1.0180000000000002,
            "systemFlags" : 1,
            "userFlags" : 0,
            "totalIndexSize" : 542395840,
            "indexSizes" : {
                    "_id_" : 10277232,
                    "make_model_year_averageRating_index" : 19319888,
                    "submodel_id_index" : 10072832,
                    "target_id_index" : 10522512,
                    "model" : 9909312,
                    "year" : 8870960,
                    "legacyId" : 6851488,
                    "author_name_index" : 10473456,
                    "author_email_index" : 15550752,
                    "ip_address_index" : 7644560,
                    "make" : 9745792,
                    "moderationStatus" : 12640096,
                    "created" : 10072832,
                    "model_make_year_status_index" : 21911680,
                    "model_make_year_status_created_index" : 25607232,
                    "submodel_id_status_created_index" : 19982144,
                    "style_id_status_created_index" : 20431824,
                    "make_status_index" : 15984080,
                    "model_year_make_created_status_index" : 25599056,
                    "submodel_id_created_status_index" : 19982144,
                    "style_id_created_status_index" : 20431824,
                    "comment_moderationStatus_index" : 6990480,
                    "make_comment_status_index" : 10285408,
                    "comment_authorName_index" : 7023184,
                    "comment_authorEmail_index" : 7227584,
                    "comment_ipAddress_index" : 7072240,
                    "comment_created_index" : 7031360,
                    "make_model_year_identifier_target_id_index" : 22827392,
                    "make_model_year_identifier_target_id_created_status_index" : 32842992,
                    "make_model_year_identifier_index" : 18706688,
                    "make_model_year_identifier_created_status_index" : 28689584,
                    "comment_id_index" : 384272,
                    "comment_updated_index" : 310688,
                    "updated" : 7309344,
                    "duplicateSearchSignature" : 6859664,
                    "author_name_created_status_index" : 20366416,
                    "sentinel_conclusion_moderation_status_index" : 13089776,
                    "created_moderation_status_sentinel_conclusion_index" : 16736272,
                    "moderation_status_sentinel_conclusion_created_index" : 16760800
            },
            "ok" : 1
    }
```

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Please provide us with some information. Add the output of `db.collection.stats()`,`db.stats()`, `db.collection.getIndices()` and the aggregation query code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply as I said I dont see the query miss an index and dont see the query itself slow form the slow logs . The call also works fine in some of other integration envs , this more looks like a network issue or some other issue

Comment: Please activate profiling for the database. I donut that this is a database problem. How much RAM do the members have?